# Duplicate Base URL When building services with intercept service

Tags: angular, angular8

First of all i apologize if i don't explain the issue as i should but i am confused a bit.

I am working on a project and the Base Url or Environment Url is set in the `InterceptService` but the problem is when i call a certain http `request` in a certain `service` the Request Url domain name is duplicated and this causes an `Error 404 not found` i tried to check how the url is built and everything seems fine. Other requests in other services are working fine even though they are built from the same interceptor as i believe

you can check the screen shot below to see the result:

[image: Screen shot of the failed request]

Here is the intercept method in  `InterceptService`

```
    intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    if (request.url.indexOf('/assets/') > -1) {
        return next.handle(request);
    }

    let me = this;
    var token = '';

    //this.authService.tokenVal.subscribe(val => {
    //  // need this basic auth for login request
    //  token = `Bearer ${val}`
    //});
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: token
        },
        url: `${environment.apiUrl}/${request.url}` 
    });

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        tap(
            event => {
                 if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.error(error.status);
                console.error(error.message);
            }
        )
    );
```

And my url in `environment.ts` seems fine as shown below:

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
apiUrl: 'http://localhost:5100',
isMockEnabled: false,
authTokenKey: '......'
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating the url when you clone the request.

```
request = request.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    Authorization: token
  },
  // url: `${environment.apiUrl}/${request.url}`  NOT THIS
  url: request.url // THIS
});
```

`${environment.apiUrl}/${request.url}` should be
`request.url`

You are cloning the request so that you can add headers, but the request url itself has already been fully defined by your code that set it as `http://localhost:5001/api/countries` in the first place

Comment: This changes the port to 4200 and i want to use the back ends 5100 port. Plus i am wondering why it is working fine for other requests in other services? thats Weird or i am missing something out.

Comment: But your screenshot shows the url `http://localhost:5100/http://localhost:5100/api/countries`. If this has come from `${environment.apiUrl}/${request.url}`, that suggests to me that `environment.baseUrl` is `http://localhost:5100`, and your http request looks something like ```http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/api/countries`)```. That means request.url is `http://localhost:5100/api/countries`

Comment: That is what confusing me. In another service the base url is built the same way yet the request is correct. I don't that the solution is in your answer.